# Book about a young man with a cat sidekick

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

The details are very vague in my mind but I'm looking for the name of a book I read probably 7-10 years ago. It is about a young man/teenager that lived in a technologically advanced society where everyone had telepathic or holographic animal familiars. His was a cat.

They all lived in a cave or mountain or somewhere that seemed very primitive relative to the level of technology they had attained. The culture is very controlled, and I think he rebels against this somehow. For some reason, the boy has to leave the city and is hunted. There is a female that he meets who leaves with him or that he meets after he has left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! It's called [*Metagame*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6499287-metagame#) by Sam Landstrom. I'll reread it now to find out just how inaccurate my description was.

> Life is a game, literally. Winners earn immortality, while losers are condemned to aging and death. D_Light, a gifted player, knows this all too well and he’s willing to do anything to win—even kill. It is no wonder then that when given the chance to enter a MetaGame—an exclusive, high-stakes, anything goes contest—he’s quick to jump at the opportunity. The MetaGame starts out well enough for D_Light, the first quest being to hunt down a dangerous fugitive, but through his own ambition, the tables turn and D_Light finds himself the renegade. Now, D_Light pits himself against his world to find the truth behind “The Game” and must decide between winning it and saving what’s left of his humanity.
>
> This book blends emerging political and cultural trends, such as gaming culture, globalization, and the ever-increasing hegemony of corporations, with technological trends, such as genetic engineering, artificial intelligence, and virtual reality. Oh, and if that is not enough, there's even some romance

Comment: Huh! Got to admit, I read that book (several years ago), and all that came to mind from your description was some books by Andre Norton.